# Alert Dialog was disappearing when user clicks out side

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Hi everyone i have a alert box with two text box's, and here the problem is the alert dialog was disappearing when user clicks outside of that pop up or the Alert dialog is disappearing when user clicks Ok button too.

So please help me in this regards
Thanks in advance...

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Sign In Failed");
final EditText input1=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
final EditText input2=new EditText(MainActivity.this);
input1.setHint("eNTER name1");
input2.setHint("Enter Name2");
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
builder.setMessage("Invalid username or password");
linearLayout.addView(input1);
linearLayout.addView(input2);
builder.setView(linearLayout);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: Hi Onkar, i have tried builder.setCancelable(false); and working fine but i have some validations in my setPositiveButton() method if i click ok button the pop up message was disappearing. please help me in this regards

Comment: my validation inside setPositive() wasif(input1.length<=0){Toast("enter name");}else{Toast("ok")}

Comment: if(input1.lenght<1)
{ 
toast ("Enter Name");
}
else 
{ 
toast ("OK");
dialog.dismiss();
}

Comment: Hi muzamil, i have tried your code sample but its not working.

Comment: Ram have you removed dialog.cancel line

Comment: my validation inside setPositive() was if(input1.length<=0){Toast("enter name");}else{Toast("ok");dialog.cancel}, ya muzamil i have used this, but the pop up was disappearing when user clicks ok button

Comment: plz click on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37987675/6422656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because by default it is Cancelable

Add this after builder.setView(linearLayout) -

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

**UPDATE**

As per your code snippet below-

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
```

on positive button ("OK") click, you are setting `dialog.cancel()` Don't do this, you should set some action as you required on positive button click.

**See This :**

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel(); // close the current dialog
        }
    });

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

           //Perform any Intent Action or perform validation as you want

         }
    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just copy & paste below code - working perfectly

```
 final EditText input1 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText input2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        input1.setHint("Enter name1");
        input2.setHint("Enter Name2");
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.addView(input1);
        linearLayout.addView(input2);

        final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Sign In Failed")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Invalid username or password").setView(linearLayout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();
        builder.show();
        builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (input1.length() <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Onkar, i have tried builder.setCancelable(false); and working fine but i have some validations in my setPositiveButton() method if i click ok button the pop up message was disappearing.  please help me in this regards

Comment: Hi ram, this is because you are setting dialog.cancel(); on OK button click. Use negative button as "Cancel" and then inside cancel click use dialog.cancel().

Comment: If you want to perform any action on positive button click then use Intent. Btw what you want to perform on OK button click??

Comment: Hi Onkar, my validation inside setPositive() was if(input1.length<=0){Toast("enter name");}else{Toast("ok");dialog.cancel}

Comment: Hi Onkar, i need to cancel the dialog when user enter's some text in input1 field, if not i need to restrict him by providing toast message and the pop up message should not be closed.

Comment: Hi Onkar, i do not need any intents in setPositiveButton() method, just if i receive the values from user the popup should be disapperaed after ok button click

Comment: Okay, please post code snippet of setPositive() method.

Comment: Hi Onkar, my validation inside setPositive() was if(input1.length<=0){Toast("enter name");}else{Toast("ok");dialog.cancel}

Comment: Okay, wait for 10 min, i will check your code and do corrections as needed

Comment: Hi Onkar, I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @ ram, After a bit research and testing i found the solution as u want, Check my UPDATE 2

Comment: Hi Onkar, the getButton method is coming, if i copy paste the code the getButton was in red color and saying cant resolve

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

Comment: did u import it as i mentioned?

Comment: Ok do one thing, cast the builder as - ((AlertDialog)builder).getButton

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987675/how-to-validate-text-boxes-in-alert-dialog-box-in-android/37987748#37987748

Comment: find the new code at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987675/how-to-validate-text-boxes-in-alert-dialog-box-in-android/37987748#37987748

Answer (score 2):

You need to set outside touch false try this:

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: This will also make the dialog disappear when user click on the backbutton, maybe that's not a problem for the OP, but I just wanted to note that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set cancelable false:

```
.setCancelable(false)
```