# how to validate text boxes in Alert Dialog box in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i am working on alert dialog with some text boxes where the text boxes needed to be validated and if they are correct only then the pop up message need to be disappeared
The problem here was, if user clicks ok button(with empty values) the pop up message was disappearing.
Thanks in advance...

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(KmsActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Enter OrderId,BillNo");
builder.setCancelable(false);
final EditText input1 = new EditText(KmsActivity.this);
final EditText input2 = new EditText(KmsActivity.this);
input1.setHint("Enter OrderId");
input2.setHint("Enter BillNo");
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(KmsActivity.this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.addView(input1);
linearLayout.addView(input2);
builder.setView(linearLayout);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface popupDialog, int which) {
        String orderId = input1.getText().toString();
        String billNo = input2.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG_NAME, "order id:" + orderId);
        Log.d(TAG_NAME, "bill no" + billNo);
        if (orderId.length()<=0) {
            Toast.makeText(KmsActivity.this, "Please enter Order ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (billNo.length()<=0) {
            Toast.makeText(KmsActivity.this, "Please enter Bill No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            tripObjects.get(0).setOrderId(orderId);
            tripObjects.get(0).setBillNo(billNo);
            tripObjects.get(0).saveInBackground();
            Toast.makeText(KmsActivity.this, "values uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            popupDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Comment: If the dialog dismisses automatically on the button pressing then you can write a custom dialog and override the click listener method (without builder using).

Comment: Hi Wax, can u give any reference link for it please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert Dialog was disappearing when user clicks out side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984723/alert-dialog-was-disappearing-when-user-clicks-out-side)

Comment: Link? Just extend your class from AlertDialog and call needed base methods in the constructor :) You also can set a custom view. I don't remember a method name, unfortunately. Maybe `setView`. If you don't want to it dismisses on the outside click, just set property `setCancelable(false)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First import class as -** `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

**Then Try this -**

```
final EditText input1 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText input2 = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        input1.setHint("Enter name1");
        input2.setHint("Enter Name2");
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.addView(input1);
        linearLayout.addView(input2);

        final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Sign In Failed")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("Invalid username or password").setView(linearLayout).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                }).create();
        builder.show();
        ((AlertDialog)builder).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (input1.length() <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Onkar, i have copy pasted u r code, its saying inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android,support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder' to /android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog'.

Comment: Please take look at my code. Its not "AlertDialog.Builder" only "AlertDialog"

Comment: check this -  final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)

Comment: its saying, required:'android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog' but found 'android,support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder'

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Comment: Error:(200, 97) error: incompatible types
required: AlertDialog
found:    Builder

Comment: Post your updated code as as update in your question

Comment: Now, is it working properly??  sorry i was little bit busy

Comment: Hi Onkar, i have used custom button in the place of positiveButton

Answer (score 1):

You can either call your text validation method on positive click button with a condition with a toast message.
or you can add addTextChangeListener to your textview where you are entering text, to call validation method everytime you change text.

Comment: Hi Ankit, i did't understood what you said, please can you give me a proper example